# <T> cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I want to change the return type of this method to a class (`ReturnContainer`) that can hold the `tupelo` object in addition to another return value that I need to send back to the calling method.

I've never worked with this `<T>` concept in Java before so I don't how to reconfigure this method to work the way I need it to.

```
public static <T extends LocationCapable> List<T> test(Class<T> incomingClass)
{
    List<TestTuple<T>> tupelo = new ArrayList<TestTuple<T>>();
    return tupelo;
}
```

When I try to change the code to the listing below, I get the error:

```
T cannot be resolved to a type
```

**How can I have a return type of `ReturnContainer` but still allow the incomingClass to be a dynamic type?**

```
public static ReturnContainer test(Class<T> incomingClass)
{
            List<TestTuple<T>> tupelo = new ArrayList<TestTuple<T>>();
            ReturnContainer rc = new ReturnContainer(tupelo, incomingClass);
    return rc;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the type parameter:

```
public static <T> ReturnContainer test(Class<T> incomingClass)
{
    List<TestTuple<T>> tupelo = new ArrayList<TestTuple<T>>();
    ReturnContainer rc = new ReturnContainer(tupelo, incomingClass);
    return rc;
}
```

To my eyes, though, this looks weird. Shouldn't `ReturnContainer` have a type parameter, too? In which case, you'd have

```
public static <T> ReturnContainer<T> test(Class<T> incomingClass)
{
    List<TestTuple<T>> tupelo = new ArrayList<TestTuple<T>>();
    ReturnContainer rc = new ReturnContainer<T>(tupelo, incomingClass);
    return rc;
}
```